# Why can't I add to a numeric object property?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, addition, numeric

If I have a simple object like this:

```
const currentAccount = [{
    name: 'J.Edge',
    balance: 100,

}]
```

Firstly, am I right in thinking (forgive my newbie-ness, only been learning JS for a few weeks) that I can't add to the numeric balance property directly, like in the function below, because of JS type coercion converting the balance property's 100 to a string?

```
const withdraw = (amount) => {
    currentAccount.balance - amount
    return Object.keys(currentAccount)

}
```

And secondly, what would be the easiest way of getting around this?

Comment: - is for subtraction ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the assignment operators `+=` and `-=`.

This is the same as writing `variable = variable + change` or `variable = variable - change`

```js
const currentAccount = [{
    name: 'J.Edge',
    balance: 100,

}];

const withdraw = (amount) => {
    currentAccount[0].balance -= amount
}

const deposit = (amount) => {
    currentAccount[0].balance += amount
}

withdraw(20); // => 100 - 20
deposit(45); // => 80 + 45

console.log(currentAccount[0].balance); // => 125
```

Note that `currentAccount` is an Array, thus you need to access an element in there before changing values.

Comment: Actually quite annoyed at myself for not remembering that it's an array... Thanks a lot Luca!

Comment: Not a problem! Glad I could be of help ;-)